# How to insert many rows into a table, after modifying each line after select?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with one field of type varchar

I want to transfer data from the table to the other, in which a change type of varhar to double

```
INSERT INTO test_table2 (
        ....
        convert(values, DECIMAL(10, 2)),
      )  SELECT values FROM test_table1;
```

Why it does not work? I guess that after select have an array of data and change type to double the entire array, I can not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be the syntax you want:

```
insert into test_table2(columnname)
    select cast(values as decimal(10, 2))
    from test_table1;
```